# Why doesn't ActionBarActivity support the setSupportActionBar()

Tags: android-toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

It's surprising that the `setSupportActionBar()` is not supported by the `ActionBarActivity`. I tried and searched a lot but every place I searched shows that it supports it.

It shows that

> setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) in ActionBarActivity cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: Did you try this _In You Activity.java import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of android.widget.Toolbar_?

Comment: Are you using this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar%28android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar%29
Acc. to documentation, it should work as traditional Toolbar.

Comment: What is the real question?

Answer (score 0):

There is `setSupportActionBar()` and `setActionBar()`. Make sure that you are using the correct one.